# Unique if not null check in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a **built-in** way to say that a field should be unique if it is not null. For example, I want users to have a unique phone number, but this is not a required field. So it can be null, and hence it breaks the unique constraint if another user is added without a phone number.

This is almost the same question: [mongoDB/mongoose: unique if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955040/mongodb-mongoose-unique-if-not-null) but with newer versions of both mongoose and mongodb, I guess there should be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: you can use Partial Index with Unique Constraint  refer:https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-partial/#partial-index-with-unique-constraints

Answer (score 5):

If you dont like to combine sparse and unique indexes like in answer you provided

```
db.users.ensureIndex({ phone: 1 }, { unique: true, sparse: true });
```

You can use [partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031658/partial-indexes-in-mongodb-mongoose), which is not implemented in mongoose, but available as a native operator.

```
db.users.createIndex(
   { phone: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { phone: { $exists: true } } }
)
```