# How do you define a partial index in mongoid ?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

MongoDB 3.2 introduced partial indexes - you can define a filter as part of the index to which the index will be applied.
In ruby's mongoid I can define a unique or normal index.

Since the partial index contains a filter expression on which the index should work - how do you define it on a model ?

Comment: You would just add a scope with the same filter on your model.  mongo's query planner should pick it up when it executes

Comment: Had the same question. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55590312/1257369

Answer (score 1):

To replicate @everyman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031658/partial-indexes-in-mongodb-mongoose/55590312#55590312) to this question (please upvote his answer too).

---

For Mongoid users:

```rb
index(
  { user_id: 1, author_id: 1, complete: 1 },
  background: true,
  partial_filter_expression: {
    complete: { :$eq => true }
  }
)
```

Couldn't find any docs, but [this PR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35031658/partial-indexes-in-mongodb-mongoose/55590312#:%7E:text=any%20docs%2C%20but-,this%20PR,-.).